# Why does my dbt container hang in Vertex AI?

Tags: docker, dbt, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

I am trying to follow [this](https://datatonic.com/insights/dbt-vertex-ai-pipelines-google-cloud/) tutorial to run a dbt docker image as a Vertex AI component. When the pipeline runs the component just seems to sit there for ever. Is there any way of debugging the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the pipeline logs to get an idea regarding what is going on in the pipeline.
From the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/logging)

> After you define and build a pipeline, you can use Cloud Logging to create log entries to help you monitor events such as pipeline failures. You can create custom log-based metrics that send notifications when the rate of pipeline failures reaches a given threshold.

You can also select a component inside Pipeline's runtime graph and then view detailed info and logs of that particular component.
[image]

Also you can hover your cursor on the component status area(green check or grey disabled icon) to check the current status of that component.

Comment: Thanks but when I look at logs, there aren't any. Do I have to create them?

Comment: That's odd when I change the severity level to something then back to default, the logs appeared!

Comment: @schoon Did you check by clicking the `refresh` button? You are right this should not be the case

Comment: Possibly not, will try that next time. Ta for your help!